# Chrome is bypassing the proxy settings on my Google Nexus 5

Tags: android, google-chrome, proxy, charles-proxy, nexus-5

I have a Nexus 5 that I bought directly from Google (in the UK). I've spent a considerable amount of time in the last couple of days trying to get the device to proxy through my laptop (using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)). However, it just won't work. No matter what I do, while trying to access any site through Chrome (the default and only browser on my device), the proxy is ignored.

I've tried proxying using the exact same method with my Nexus 7 device and all works well.

I've tried:

- Soft resets
- Clearing the cache on Chrome on the device
- Various combinations of connecting and disconnecting from the wifi network, removing and reinstating the proxy settings
- Followed [these instructions](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#virtual-host-mapping) to the letter (and varied it where possible)

It's driving me mad. I have two similar Android devices with identical settings, sat side-by-side and one will play ball, but the other won't.

I've Googled around a lot with no success, I was just wondering if anyone else has encountered this? A fix would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This may be caused by having the Data Compression Proxy enabled, which causes Chrome to ignore your manually configured HTTP proxy settings as plain traffic becomes routed over SPDY to Google's proxy server.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/data-compression

Answer (score 0):

I am the lead on the Chrome data compression proxy. If you can go to chrome://net-internals in Chrome and save a trace, and file a bug at crbug.com with the details (feel free to email me or update this thread with the bug ID) that would be very helpful. Also, have you tried a non-Chrome browser (e.g., Firefox)?